# What's the mathematical name to scale a number to a new resolution

Tags: terminology

From a programmers background, i know what  i need to accomplish, and how i should, but i don't know if there's a mathematical name for what i'm doing here...

For examle, i have the number 5 in a range from 0 to 100.
I need to calculate the equivalent value in a new range, let's say from 0 to 500.

This new value is obviously 25, and i know how to calculate it.

The question is, is there a mathematical name for this type of conversion??

Comment: I'd call it scaling. Or in general you could be talking about proportions.

Comment: @user4894 Thanks for your answer, i thought there was a more mathematical description...

Comment: Why the downvote, and why not leave a comment so i can learn something?

Comment: Coefficient? Factor? Scalar? Scaling factor? Magnifying factor? Zoom factor?